# statistics on individual path agents

Tags: anylogic

I am simulating a medical stay and would like to calculate for each patient generated the cost of their stay. I have created a parameter that is updated each time the patient receives care. However, to plot it, I created a histogram data with a cyclic event that updates the values every hour with the following code:

```
this.CostperPatient.reset();
for (Patient patients: this.patients)
    { 
                   this.CostperPatient.add(patients.cost);
    }
```

However, the chart it produces does not give an indication of individual patients, it makes a percentage.
Is there any way to output a graph with the cost for each individual patient?

Thank U
Miriana

Comment: Hi Miriana, could you please clarify what you want to see exactly? This is how histograms work, they show you the percentage distribution by cost in your case. So for example if 1 patient cost 100$ and 2 others 200$, you will have 2 bars, 33% height for 100$ and 67% for 200$. What is it you want to see alternatively?

Comment: Yes, I want to see, reffering to your example, 3 bar one for each patient. It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not sure what you are trying to show, it seems that in your case, you shouldn't be using a histogram, instead you should probably use a bar chart where each bar is for a patient. To do so, drag to your model in the main environment a bar chart element and call it *chart*. To dynamically add bars to this element, you need to use something called "data items". For now, remove all data items from the chart by clicking on the X in the properties.

Then, go to the Agent window, so your patients' agent window. Add a variable. Set it as follows:
[image]

Then, in the agent's properties, in the on startup field write the following:
[image]

Finally, add a cyclic event in the agent's window with the following code:

```
patientCost.setValue(cost);
```

Where cost in the above, refers to your initial variable called cost in the question. That should do it.

Comment: Ok, I have some problems!  So, I have a population of patients, these are characterized by a set of parameters, I just want to monitor a "cost" of them and this is a parameter that you have for each patient generated. I want to get a graph with the number of bars equal to the number of patients generated, each bar represents the cost of a patient. 
I don't quite understand where I need to set this code. Do I need to create a function in the Main? Do I have to insert it in the "value" of the barchart? And how do I make it iterative over all patients?

Comment: Too many questions in 1 comment. I'll try to be as helpful as possible. 1 Create an a empty bar chart in main (leave it empty don't insert value, this will be done dynamically in 2). 2. I am assuming your patient agent has a statechart? If so, in the entry action field of the state where cost becomes known (e.g. treatment complete), you add the code in my answer. Make sure to add "main." before "chart" and replace the 5 with the agent parameter.

Comment: my patient agent does not have a stats chart. I used an event to update the data, with the code I reported at the beginning! Can I put your code in the event? I want to both update the existing costs, which are a parameter of the agent, (because the patient every time he receives care will update his cost) and add new patients to the statistics!
I know it's complicated, sorry
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I updated the answer above. It should work now. If it does, please accept this answer to make sure others can benefit from it.